# iOS 7: Status bar stays black until "refresh"

Tags: ios7, statusbar, redraw

In one of my apps the status bar is black (not hidden, just the content like the time and carrier string are missing) upon launch for every view controller. Once I pushed or tapped to another view controller and go back the information appears.

Anyone else having this issue? Hints?

Thanks
–f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was just an issue with the size of the background image of the `UINavigationBar`.